# Find the greatest number

Tags: c#

Please could someone help me find the greatest number of a string? Here's the code:

```
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    int max = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
         bookNo = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
         int i = Convert.ToInt32(bookNo.Substring(bookNo.Length - 1));
         if (i > max)
         {

         }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Home work not allowed

Comment: for ease you do it in Sql too

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in one-liner

```
int max = dt.Rows
           .Select(x=>Convert.ToInt32(x.ItemArray[0].ToString().Substring(bookNo.Length-1)))
           .Max();
```